# How to fade in results in query, in this script

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein

I am creating a virtual map of a country, in which when you click on a dot as shown in this picture, below. Now, everything works fine, like you click a red dot, an image and description about the relevant region appears, and when click other red dots the previous one fades away and a new one appears. Perfect! Only problem is, then you select a town / zone from the drop down form, it only pops up the red dots, but I need the image & description also to appear for that selected town/zone.

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bTWBh/)

To know the problem, you should click on a red dot first, then when you see the image/description pop up, then select from the drop down menu any zone and even though you will see the the dot only appearing, but the description / image never changes when you select the zone automatically.

thanks for the help

[image]

Here is the JS code, are below as the site won't let me only post the jsFiddle link.

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// begin Ready

    //...................................................
    // When the form changes
    $('#mapForm').change(function() {

        var selectedContinent = $('#mapForm option:selected').val();
        if (selectedContinent == 'ALL'){
            $('a.dot').slideDown(1000);

        }else{
            $('a.dot[continent = "'+selectedContinent+'"]').slideDown(1000);
            $('a.dot[continent != "'+selectedContinent+'"]').slideUp(1000);
            $('a.dott[continent = "'+selectedContinent+'"]').slideDown(1000);
            $('a.dott[continent != "'+selectedContinent+'"]').slideUp(1000);
        }

    });

    $('#mapFormm').change(function() {

        var selectedContinentt = $('#mapFormm option:selected').val();
        if (selectedContinentt == 'ALL'){

            $('a.dott').slideDown(1000);
        }else{
            $('a.dot[continent = "'+selectedContinentt+'"]').slideDown(1000);
            $('a.dot[continent != "'+selectedContinentt+'"]').slideUp(1000);
            $('a.dott[continent = "'+selectedContinentt+'"]').slideDown(1000);
            $('a.dott[continent != "'+selectedContinentt+'"]').slideUp(1000);
        }

    });

    // When a dot is clicked
    //...................................................
    $('a.dot').click(function(){

        $('a.dot').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');

        var city = '.city_detail#' + $(this).attr('city');
        var htmlCode = $(city).html();

        $('.detail_container').fadeOut(500, function(){
            $('.detail_container .city_detail').html(htmlCode);
            $('.detail_container').fadeIn(500);
        });

    });
    $('a.dott').click(function(){

        $('a.dott').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');

        var city = '.city_detail#' + $(this).attr('city');
        var htmlCode = $(city).html();

        $('.detail_container').fadeOut(500, function(){
            $('.detail_container .city_detail').html(htmlCode);
            $('.detail_container').fadeIn(500);
        });

    });

// end Ready
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just trigger click events on the elements when you are selecting them on the list

```
// When the form changes
$('#mapForm').change(function() {

    var selectedContinent = $('#mapForm option:selected').val();
    if (selectedContinent == 'ALL'){
        $('a.dot').slideDown(1000);

    }else{
        $('a.dot[continent = "'+selectedContinent+'"]').slideDown(1000, function(){$(this).trigger('click');});
        $('a.dot[continent != "'+selectedContinent+'"]').slideUp(1000);
        $('a.dott[continent = "'+selectedContinent+'"]').slideDown(1000, function(){$(this).trigger('click');});
        $('a.dott[continent != "'+selectedContinent+'"]').slideUp(1000);
    }

});

$('#mapFormm').change(function() {

    var selectedContinentt = $('#mapFormm option:selected').val();
    if (selectedContinentt == 'ALL'){

        $('a.dott').slideDown(1000);
    }else{
        $('a.dot[continent = "'+selectedContinentt+'"]').slideDown(1000, function(){$(this).trigger('click');});
        $('a.dot[continent != "'+selectedContinentt+'"]').slideUp(1000);
        $('a.dott[continent = "'+selectedContinentt+'"]').slideDown(1000, function(){$(this).trigger('click');});
        $('a.dott[continent != "'+selectedContinentt+'"]').slideUp(1000);
    }

});
```

See working [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/bTWBh/1/)

Comment: Thank, but why does it work in the demo, but when I copied and replaced my JS with your code, or even from the demo my map stopped working. Is there something I should know?

Comment: I can only think of copy/paste error, don't know any other reason.

Answer (score 1):

You need to trigger a `click` on the newly appeared elements (*the first would be wise*)

```
$('#mapForm').change(function() {
    var selectedContinent = $('#mapForm option:selected').val();
    if (selectedContinent == 'ALL'){
        $('a.dot').slideDown(1000);

    }else{
        $('a.dot[continent = "'+selectedContinent+'"]').slideDown(1000).first().click();
        $('a.dot[continent != "'+selectedContinent+'"]').slideUp(1000);
        $('a.dott[continent = "'+selectedContinent+'"]').slideDown(1000);
        $('a.dott[continent != "'+selectedContinent+'"]').slideUp(1000);
    }

});

$('#mapFormm').change(function() {

    var selectedContinentt = $('#mapFormm option:selected').val();
    if (selectedContinentt == 'ALL'){

        $('a.dott').slideDown(1000);
    }else{
        $('a.dot[continent = "'+selectedContinentt+'"]').slideDown(1000).first().click();
        $('a.dot[continent != "'+selectedContinentt+'"]').slideUp(1000);
        $('a.dott[continent = "'+selectedContinentt+'"]').slideDown(1000);
        $('a.dott[continent != "'+selectedContinentt+'"]').slideUp(1000);
    }

});
```